# Sharepoint 2013 - FBA and 2FA with custom login page

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, 12factor

I'm a complete noob in Sharepoint. I've just started learning sharepoint 2 weeks ago coz my boss assigned me to a sharepoint project. I have to implement 2FA and FBA in an existing claims based intranet web application. I though it would be a simple task to do just by researching but I haven't found a clear guide or answer for my question.

Here are a few of my tasks:

1) Add forms based authentication to the site and use custom login page.

2) Authentication

- Check user's name and password with AD upon login.
- If valid, have to request OTP code from the 3rd party provider for
  2FA.
- User is authenticated after passing both.

Configurations and custom login page were not much trouble and it didn't take long to get them done. But I'm stuck at the 2FA part.

1) How to customize the authentication process? I don't remember where did I get the below code but I really hoped that I would be able to do something with it. So, can I do something with it or I'm going the wrong path? I'd really appreciate any help and thanks a lot in advance.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool status = SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(
            Context.Request.UrlReferrer,
            txtUsername.Value.ToString(),
            txtPassword.Value.ToString());

        if (!status) // if auth failed
        {
            lblInvalid.InnerText = "Wrong Username or Password";
            lblInvalid.Visible = true;
        }
        else //if success
        {       
    //What do I do here to change the user back to not authenticated?   

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you properly log in set federated authentication cookie domain.

```
HttpCookie httpCookie = current.Response.Cookies["FedAuth"];
httpCookie.Domain = "." + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourdomain"];
```

Sign out method is more complicated, long time ago i based my solution on [this post](http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/fixing-sharepoint-claims-authentication-and-sign-out?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/security)

And sign out method (sorry for variable names but i'm decompiling my old dll) based on sharepoint SignOut page and fix from the post:

```
public static void SignOut(SPSite site, SPWeb web, IClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    if (current.Session != null)
    {
        current.Session.Clear();
    }
    string value = string.Empty;
    if (current.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"] == "false")
    {
        value = "NoCookie";
    }
    HttpCookie httpCookie = current.Request.Cookies["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated"];
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < current.Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpCookie httpCookie2 = current.Request.Cookies.Get(i);
        if (httpCookie2.Name == "FedAuth" && !flag)
        {
            flag = true;
            httpCookie2.Domain =  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourdomain"];
        }
    }
    if (httpCookie != null)
    {
        httpCookie.Value = value;
        current.Response.Cookies.Remove("WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated");
        current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    }
    HttpCookie httpCookie3 = current.Request.Cookies["MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie"];
    if (httpCookie3 != null)
    {
        httpCookie3.Value = value;
        httpCookie3.Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        current.Response.Cookies.Remove("MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie");
        current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie3);
    }
    SPIisSettings iisSettingsWithFallback = site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(site.Zone);
    if (iisSettingsWithFallback.UseClaimsAuthentication)
    {
        string iPUrl = Authentication.GetIPUrl(principal);
        if (iPUrl != string.Empty)
        {
            string str = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url);
            string url = iPUrl + "?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=" + str;
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
            if (current.Session != null)
            {
                current.Session.Abandon();
            }
            current.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
            int num = 0;
            foreach (SPAuthenticationProvider current2 in iisSettingsWithFallback.ClaimsAuthenticationProviders)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (num != 1 || !iisSettingsWithFallback.UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication)
            {
                if (current.Session != null)
                {
                    current.Session.Abandon();
                }
                SPUtility.Redirect(web.ServerRelativeUrl, 0, current);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if (AuthenticationMode.Forms == SPSecurity.AuthenticationMode)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        if (current.Session != null)
        {
            current.Session.Abandon();
        }
        SPUtility.Redirect(web.ServerRelativeUrl, 0, current);
    }
    else if (AuthenticationMode.Windows != SPSecurity.AuthenticationMode)
    {
        throw new SPException();
    }
}

private static string GetIPUrl(IClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    string result;
    if (principal == null)
    {
        result = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string text2 = principal.Identity.Name.Split(new char[] {'|'})[1];
            if (SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.Local.TrustedLoginProviders[text2] != null)
            {
                text = SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.Local.TrustedLoginProviders[text2].ProviderUri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
        }
        result = text;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Further reading:**

- [Writing A Custom Forms Login Page for SharePoint 2010](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/writing-a-custom-forms-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1/)
- [Custom Single Sign-On Scenario in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akirsman/2012/05/09/custom-single-sign-on-scenario-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering tinamou. I really appreciate your help. I'm gonna try it as soon as I get to work tomorrow. Btw do I have to sign out your way if I'm gonna re-signin on the same page? I mean, I'm planning to hide the login controls after authenticating with AD and show the controls to do 2FA. After successful 2FA, user will be authenticated and redirected to the home page.

Comment: Don't re-signin, your signin page and second authentication part should be aware that first part succeeded:  "MFA Server lets the application do its own primary auth and then evaluates the web response to see if the primary auth succeeded or failed"

Comment: The 2FA API will return just success or exception codes when linking/unlinking SMS device or authenticating. I might be wrong but its what I understand so far after reading their API doc. In that case, signing the user out after successfully authentication with AD is still bad? The plan I have is : 1) authenticate user with AD 2) sign the user out after authenticated (to prevent user entering url and access the site without doing 2FA) 3) do the 2FA (with their API methods) 4) Authenticate the user again to give access. I'm a noob. Pls fix me if i'm going so wrong. :)

Comment: seems valid, but maybe there is a possibility for async check, without signin, and signin only after 2FA succeeds, i'll think about this...

Comment: Please lemme know when you have better solution. Btw I marked yours as answer coz it did help me. Thank you!

Comment: try using `SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication` to check user credentials and after 2fa succeeds use `SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser` to give access to site

Answer (score 0):

**Normal aspx page**

```
<html>
<head>One Head</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnButton" Text="Button" OnClick="btnButton_Click" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You may have trouble in adding Microsoft.SharePoint.identityModel, here is the location I got

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll
```

**List of Includes**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

**Button click code**

```
protected void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string domn = "mydomain";

    string membershipProviderName = "membership";
    string roleProviderName = "rolemanager";
    string cookieeee = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", domn, txtUserName.Text);
    bool isAuthenticated = Authenticate(domn, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), 
            membershipProviderName, roleProviderName, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, 
            SPFormsAuthenticationOption.PersistentSignInRequest);
        SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token);
        Response.Redirect("/");
    }
}

[DirectoryServicesPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
public static bool Authenticate(string domainName, string userAlias, string userPassword)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
        return context.ValidateCredentials(userAlias, userPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate));
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note: **Make sure you have all FBA configurations set** in web config files. This is only custom authentication **this will not work if role and membership are not set properly** in the central admin and web config on services and webapplication.

Comment: For FBA setup  - http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-form-based-authentication-using-active-directory/